# is there any Mathematical notation to show must happen or may happen events?

Tags: probability

There are two types of events

1- it will must happen

2- it may or may not happen depending on previous circumstances.

```
Must happening event: NT ∪ {NTn} and ETH ∪ { ETHn }  (given: n=1)
May happen event: NA ∪ {NAn} and NH ∪ {NHn}   ( given: n=1 ∨ n>=1)
```

Must happening event is **we will add 1 new element in set**.

May happen event is we may add **new elements in set if it is not already there**.

Do we have any mathamtical notaions for that? I am not in math major so I am not sure, what i am looking is really math or something else.

Comment: Always better to use words for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You put the *probability* tag on your question, but there is nothing about probability in the question.   So I will answer both for probability theory, and for other ideas that fit better with the way that you put things.

You have at least two ideas here.  One concerns whether something must happen or might not happen.  The other is the idea is that the "must" and "may" are conditional on other things happening.  A third idea concerns adding things to a set.

---

**Without probability:**

Note that if something must happen, then it also may happen.  If you mean to use "may" to imply not must, then what you mean is possibly, and possibly not.  We also say "necessarily" instead of "must" in mathematical logic.

The the standard notation for *necessarily* is "$\Box$".  The standard notion for *possibly* is "$\diamond$".

So event $A$ must happens, is $\Box A$.  To say that $A$ might happen, but it might not, you can write $\diamond A \;\&\; \neg\! \diamond\! A$, where $\neg$ means *not*.

For the conditional, it looks like you might mean if/then: If $n=1$ then $A$.  If you want a symbol for if/then, people use various kinds of right arrows, as in $(n=1) \rightarrow A$.  In mathematical logic some people use "$\supset$" instead of an arrow; this symbol has a different meaning in set theory.

---

**Using probability:**

In probability theory, to say that an event $A$ must happen, you say that its probability is 1: $\mathsf{P}(A)=1$.  (Actually, this is not precisely correct, but at this stage of learning, it will be close enough.)

If you want to say that event $A$ has some chance of occurring, but is not guaranteed to occur, you can say that it has a probability is less than 1: $\mathsf{P}(A) < 1$.

If you want to say that $A$ cannot happen, that's $\mathsf{P}(A) = 0$.  (Again, this is not strictly correct, but it's a good starting point for now.)

If you want to think in terms of probability, and that's why you're using "given", then if/then is not the right relationship.  Then I think you want to use conditional probability.  The conditional probability that $A$ will occur, given that $B$ occurs (or is true), is written $\mathsf{P}(A|B)$.  For most purposes this can be defined as:

$$\mathsf{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathsf{P}(A \& B)}{\mathsf{P}(B)}$$

---

Finally, I think you know, basically, how to notate unions between sets.  Just remember that if $a$ is the sort of thing that can go in set $S$, since the union operator connects two sets, write $\{a\} \cup S$, where $\{a\}$ is the set containing only $a$.